# HTML: Defining a table via column

Tags: html, twig, html-table

I'm facing a Problem:

I need to display a table in HTML using twig, but my object `scores` represent the column, not the row (`score.name`, `score.value`). Of course I could display each row using multiple for, but I wanted to know if it's possible to create a table via it's column? or if there is a Twig function to do this easily ?

```
{% for score in scores %}
    {% if loop.first %}<table class="table">{% endif %}
        //HERE I got column
    {% if loop.last %}</table>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The rendered table should then looks like:

```
|score1.name |score2.name |score3.name |etc...
|------------|------------|------------|--------
|score1.value|score2.value|score3.value|etc...
```

where `score1`, `score2`, `score3` are the `score` in `scores` loop

So in html it  should looks like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>score1.name</th>
        <td>score1.value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>score2.name</th>
        <td>score2.value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>score3.name</th>
        <td>score3.value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>etc...</th>
        <td>etc...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is `score` also an array?

Comment: @GentlemanMax Thank you for your interest. `score` is an object, I can access data using `$score->getName()`, `$score->getValue()`

Comment: Oh, is it a single column of data?

Comment: Yes, each `score` represent a column with head : `score.name` and body containing only `score.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use twig variables and build the table like this:

```
{% set rowName = "" %}
{% set rowScore = "" %}
{% for score in scores %}
    {% set rowName = rowName~"<td>"~score.name~"</td>" %}
    {% set rowScore = rowScore~"<td>"~score.value~"</td>" %}
{% endfor %}
<table class="table">
    <tr>{{ rowName }}</tr>
    <tr>{{ rowScore }}</tr>  
</table>
```

This way you build the rows in the loop and then output them once they are built.  Ideally an operation like this should be happening before `scores` get to Twig but if you need to do it in twig this way should work.

Comment: You just forgot " at the end of `{% set rowScore = rowScore~"<td>"~score.value~"</td> %}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your mapping done correctly in Doctrine, it should be easy. I'll presume your Score Entity has a way to get the related event, something like `getEvent()` and then the Event Entity might have a name method like `getName()`; then you could code like so:

```
<table class="table">
<tr><th>Event name</th><th>Score Name</th><th>Score Value</th></tr>
{% for score in scores %}
    <tr><td>score.getEvent.getName</td><td>score.getName</td><td>score.getValue</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

I think that should help you out.

Comment: This will display rows of score, while I would like to display column of score i.e. the first row is the `score.name` and the second one `score.value`

Comment: Does it alternate? For example: `<tr><td>score.name</td></tr><tr><td>score.value</td></tr><tr><td>score.name</td></tr><tr><td>score.value</td></tr><tr><td>score.name</td></tr><tr><td>score.value</td></tr>`. It would be good if you edited your post to show a `full` example of a table with sample data filled in so we can really give you a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, in fact I could have tried to be more precise, but that was clear in my head, then I didn't think about all that possible options... Anyway, @GentlemanMax give an answer. I will edit my question to be clear for the others.